# HtmlAgilityPack - How to understand page redirected and load redirected page

Tags: c#, redirect, html-agility-pack

With using HtmlAgilityPack and c# 4.0 how can you determine whether page is being redirected or not. I am using this method to load page.

```
HtmlDocument hdMyDoc = hwWeb.Load(srPageUrl);
```

And example redirection result i suppose

Returned inner html

```
<meta http-equıv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.pratikev.com/fractalv33/pratikEv/pages/home.jsp">
```

c# 4.0

Comment: Note that the HTTP spec has status codes for re-direction, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3 - I'm not sure about how to detect this using HtmlAgilityPack but it's worth being aware that an HTML meta tag is not the only redirection method. Another redirection method which may be used is client side Javascript, which could be very difficult to detect via static analysis.

Comment: yes javascript would be very hard . but i can at least detect meta redirect  i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **this case**, parse the HTML is the best way.

```
var page = "...";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(page);
var root = doc.DocumentNode;
var select = root.SelectNodes("//meta[contains(@content, 'URL')]");
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("has redirect..");
    Console.WriteLine(select[0].Attributes["content"].Value.Split('=')[1]);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("have not redirect using HTML");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the document is relatively well-formed, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
static string GetMetaRefreshUrl(string sourceUrl)
{
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(sourceUrl);
    var xpath = "//meta[@http-equiv='refresh' and contains(@content, 'URL')]";
    var refresh = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (refresh == null)
        return null;
    var content = refresh.Attributes["content"].Value;
    return Regex.Match(content, @"\s*URL\s*=\s*([^ ;]+)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
}
```